# How can you start/stop Bluetooth on 22.04 at the command line?

Tags: command-line, 22.04, bluetooth

Dell Vostro 2520 laptop
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Bluetooth does not show up in the drop menu at the right end of the window title bar. The Bluetooth page in the Settings app says that **Bluetooth Turned Off**. After I click the slider toggle in the top RH corner of the Bluetooth page, the slider does not highlight and the **Bluetooth Turned Off** message does not change.

How can I switch Bluetooth on and off from the command line, and pair with other devices, in this case, a Bluetooth keyboard?

Comment: You can try in terminal `bluetoothctl` then `power on` and `scan on` and see if it works